# Android Web App JSON parsing vs Server Side

Tags: android, json, parsing, client-side

I need some advice about JSON parsing on the client side for an Android/iOS hybrid app. I'm currently using CouchDB as the main database. The problem is that each response of the DB is ~1200 lines of JSON, which  needs to be parsed, however, I'm only using around 5% of it.

I can't modify the data structure in the DB, so my question is, should I implement a backend server to fetch/parse the data and only send the needed result to the app or continue to do everything on the client side?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement a back-end to fetch/parse the data. There is no point in downloading tons of data that you won't use.  Also, this allows you to make changes to the database structure without having to release a new version of the application.